# why while loop is used for non-dying processes?

Tags: operating-system, while-loop

For applications  that shouldn't die, should implement while loop, afaik. 
like

```
while(){
  key = getKeyPress();
  if(key)
    processKey(key);

}
```

I can see 200 programs hanging on when I use "top". That means there are 200 while loops!

I expect every program to put hook for the events to the operating sys. When these events occur operating sys to call these hooks of program.

Web programmes executes javascript codes at the initialization. Then we hook for a button if clickes ($('button').click(myClickJs)), we hook for timer (setInterval) etc.  We dont use a loop to wait whole events on a page. Such a approach saves much cpu time and resource.

Why there isn't  such approach?

Comment: I can't figure out what you are asking. Why isn't there *what* approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "applications that shouldn't die", a loop MUST be implemented somewhere.  You can not get around this.

In your example code, it is waiting for a key to be pressed before doing what needs to be done in response to that key press.  After the key press is detected and processed, how do you reset it to wait for another key press (or other type of input)?  The answer of course is to use a loop (as you have done).

This "outer" loop does not in any way reflect upon what is going on inside the routine 'getKeyPress()'.  There are two modes in which this routine might possibly operate--polling and blocking.

If this is a polling routine, your example code will effectively busy-wait until a key is pressed.  This is known to be an inefficient use of the processor (though for some problems it is the right solution).

If this is a blocking routine, the thread/task will block until such time as a key is pressed.  While blocked, this thread/task will not be consuming any processor cycles, which will allow them to be used by another thread/task/process.  For the purposes of this response, the specific details on how this blocking call is implemented are irrelevant.  The important concept is that the thread/task may block.

Without the "outer" loop, you will only get one pass at detecting and processing any key presses, whether you have hooks or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm just curious of that. For regular program expects mouse events, timer, key, network activity. So blocking should not work. I think cpu's are faster. So no body cares.

Comment: For programs that expect multiple input sources, blocking calls may still work, but the program design may change.  1. Block waiting for any input.  2. Determine type of input.  3.  Process input.  4.  Loop back to "1".  For programs that need other work to occur while waiting for input, use another thread.

Comment: Also, though it is true that CPUs are faster than they once were, the application you write is often not the only one in use on the system.  When several applications needlessly chew up processor time, then it affects the user's productivity and experience with other applications.  As a developer, I am not in position to say which application is more important to the user, and I want them to have as pleasant an experience as practical.